# Azure cloud console clouddrive folder has unmounted and can't seem to get it back

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-clouddrive

Up until recently when I log into the cloud console in portal.com I would have a folder under /home// called clouddrive.

I'm confident this file share still exists because I can click on the upload/download files button and go to manage file share and all my files will still be there, however, when I ls in the  folder it is apparently empty apart from a folder called Microsoft which I don't remember from previously but contains the following structure: "Microsoft/Windows/PowerShell/AzPredictor".

I have gone through the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage both to add a new storage and to attempt to re-mount the old one but although it doesn't throw any errors, in neither instance does the drive come back.

When I run (Get-CloudDrive | Get-AzStorageAccount).Location I get the message the drive is not mounted.

I ran df and found the drive had been mounted on /usr/csuser/clouddrive

according to https://edyoung.github.io/blog/cloud_shell_files/ this is normal, however, it should also be visible under home yet mine is not (even with restarting the shell)

is this a bug?

Has anyone encountered and knows how to fix it? it's inconvenient to have to change drive every time I log in

Comment: This question should be on [sf], not here - it is not programming-related. But even on ServerFault, you'll need more specifics, to show all details (and please format your PowerShell correctly when you post, along with showing exact error output)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a storage account and  file share in it, I have created in Location Central India.

[image]

> I get the message the drive is not mounted.

To mount the storage account to clouddrive, you need to use below command and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#prerequisites-for-manual-mounting):

```
clouddrive mount -s "mySubscription" -g "myresourcegroup" -n "storageAccountName" -f "fileShareName"
```

[image]

After mounting you can use below command:

```
(Get-CloudDrive | Get-AzStorageAccount).Location
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: the OP isn't asking how to mount a drive - they mentioned that they *already had one* and can no longer see it. There is no need for a custom tutorial either - this isn't what Stack Overflow is for. Lastly: this isn't a programming question. This question should be closed (it belongs on [sf], although as written it would be closed there as well, for lack of detail).

Comment: Yeah this isn't the issue, the problem is that the default cloud drive is no longer mounted when I open the console in Azure.